# Can closure and deletion stats be added to the admin analytics or 10k tools?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, deleted-questions, moderator-tools

Diamond moderators get access to some site analytics relating to traffic.

Both diamond moderators and 10k+ users have access to some aggregate migration statistics like number of questions migrated to each site and migration failure rate.

These are both great, but it would be nice to be able to get aggregate data and graphs for closures and deletions. Like the site analytics page, it'd be nice to be able to get daily, weekly, monthly, and custom time period graphs for that data.

The use case for this would be for cross-analysis with other known metrics: for example, if moderation has any correlation to traffic or [for comparing regular moderation activity with migrations](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/which-questions-shouldnt-have-been-migrated-to-programmers-and-why).

If extended to 10k+ users, it'd help improve overall accountability of community moderation, as it's difficult to get a general picture of what's going on from the closed/deleted dashboards (you have to count them yourself).

Plus, graphs are neato-keen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was added on or around November 9th: [waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) let us know about it in TL. Moderators can now see closure and deletion rates in the analytics panel.